# How to convert Ruby's SHA512.hexdigest to C#?

Tags: c#, ruby, security, hash

I'm re-writing a Rails web app in C#. I'm really stuck with Ruby's hash function:

```
# Generates a 128 character hash
def Password.hash(password,salt)
  Digest::SHA512.hexdigest("#{password}:#{salt}")
end
```

The following C# function gives a different result:

```
 private static string Hash(string password, string salt)
 {
     return BitConverter.ToString(new SHA512CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password + ":" + salt))).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
 }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: What do the results look like in each case? Does Ruby actually use UTF-8?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Never mind. The results actually **ARE** the same. So if you ever need to convert Ruby's hashing to C#,

```
Digest::SHA512.hexdigest(some_string)
```

does the same as

```
BitConverter.ToString(new SHA512CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(someString))).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
```

C# is a lot more verbose, but the main thing is that it works! :)

Comment: Awesome. Same is valid for its cousin in Python.